# How does mutation work?

Tags: evolva

The manual explains the mutation UI pretty well, but does a really bad job of explaining the mechanics. Here's what I've figured out so far:

- Clicking "mutate" consumes a mutation point and randomly generates two possible mutations.
- Choosing a mutation "locks it in" and further mutations become modifications to that
- Click "mutate" again instead re-rolls
- You can repeat the above until you run out of points
- At any point, you can click "apply" to apply the selected mutation or "cancel" to back out without doing anything, but in either case all the points you spent are gone forever

The bit that's confusing me is how bonuses and penalties are generated. The first time you click Mutate, you tend to get mutations with nothing but small bonuses, or with medium penalties but very large bonuses. If you select one of those, the following mutations have much smaller and more balanced effects, basically letting you "tune" the first one -- so you might select +4 Claws/+4 Speed, and then refine that into +6 Claws/+2 Speed by repeatedly picking +1 Claws/-1 Speed sub-mutations.

What I can't figure out is what counts as a "first time". If you just roll the first mutation (call it the "bonus mutation"), accept it as is, and then go back into the mutation screen and keep rolling, you get nothing but tuning mutations. But if you leave it alone and play for a while, your next mutation will be a bonus mutation instead.

So, what determines the occurrence of bonus mutations? Is it every ten points collected, or enemies killed? Every 20 minutes played? Or is it something more subtle, like every mutation point you collect giving a slight one-time positive bias to the RNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow that is an old game. The following is completely from memory:

What kind of mutations you can select depends completely on how many enemies you have killed (= evolution points you collected). For example:

I think i remember that when you get a new weapon type, sometimes you don't have the option to mutate it without accepting some penalty. However once you killed enough enemies (of that type? i don't quite remember), you can evolve that new weapon without penalty. So basically the more enemies you kill before mutation, the better the mutation you can select. I think the bonuses you get from the collected mutation points (= killed enemies) get completely used up by the first mutation you do.

Also i think the enemy type determines what kind of bonus you get. If you killed a bunch of enemies with claws, you will get bonuses for claws, etc.

Comment: That pretty much lines up with what I remember as well, though like our esteemed answerer it's been quite a while since I played.